# Creating best API: Upload N files and json metadata

Tags: rest, http, api-design

I am creating an API.

I am unsure what the API should look like.

Several BLOB files (PDF, JPG, ZIP, ...) should get uploaded and
some JSON which contains meta data.

What is the most up-to-date way to design the API?

There are two cases:

- the upload was successful. Then I think 201 (created) would be feasible
- the upload was not successful (for example invalid meta data). Then 422 (Unprocessable Entity) should get returned.

Example:

- Three pdf-files should get uploaded (at once) associated with some json meta data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you often see is that you have a resource for handling the BLOBs and one for the meta-data - Facebook and Twitter is doing this for images and videos.

For example `/files` would take your BLOB data and return an ID for the uploaded BLOB data.

The metadata would be send to another resource, called `/posts` and could consume `application/json`.

In the application I currently work for, we had the same issue and decided to use one endpoint consuming `multipart/form-data` - here you can send the BLOBs and the metadata within different boundaries and have everything in one resource.

Another way would be to `base64` encode the BLOBs, which will result in an 33 % overhead, and I therefore not recommend it. But with base64 you could do all your work in one `application/json` resource.